# Check if data contains multiple instances of the same character

Tags: sql

I'm making a school assignment in SQL and now I have to check if a surname for example contains the letter 'o' twice in random order. (Like "morgon")

```
select ex_surname
from surname
where ex_surname like '%o%';
```

Example above gives me all instances where the letter 'o' is present, how can I filter it to give me the surnames that have 2 or more 'o' in their name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps

```
where ex_surname like '%o%o%';
```

`%` is a substitute for **zero** or more characters.

Comment: Oh okay, feel so stupid right now didn't think this was possible. Thanks a lot!